# Как лучше всего сделать логику глубины клеток?

Tags: unity3d

Допустим у меня есть некий массив клеток, где каждая клетка  должна иметь глубину N.
Сама механика должна выглядеть так: игрок может 'раскопать' любую клетку кликнув на неё. Клетку можно раскапывать N раз до тех пор, пока игрок не дойдет до максимальной глубины. После этого кликать на клетку нельзя. После того, как максимальная глубина клетки  достигнута в ней случайно появляется некий предмет.

Как это лучше всего сделать? Стоит ли создавать N  дочерних клонов к основной клетки или стоит работать с Buttom?.

Comment: Его Величество Знание, Истина в Последней Инстанции, Непоколебимый Источник Информации **Википедия** не дает определения `глубине клетки`. Дополните вопрос подробностями

Comment: дополнил. надеюсь стало понятней)

Comment: Судя по изменению механика похожа на марио: много раз долбим по квадратику и ничего не получаем (или получаем как в марио монетку), а при последнем ударе получаем бонус и кнопка деактивируется, так? Если да, то почему бы не создать класс этой кнопки, которая будет считать, сколько раз на нее нажали?